# Intuition about when an index scan _might_ be better than lots of seeks

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to gain an intuition of when an index scan might be bad and when it might actually be better than the equivleant set of seeks.

For example, take this query plan:

[image]

From the result of a previous operation we have 21k records. They match 1 to 1 with a subset of records in some index and the result of the join is still 21k records.

For the purposes of this question - assume that the index contains all required columns and thus no later key lookup is required, also assume that each seek would produce exactly 1 row.

When I looked at this my first thought was that this should be a loop join, but then I thought - that's 21k index seeks, perhaps not.

I have no intuitive sense of whether scanning 646k records is better or worse than 21k index seeks.

I *could* try to tweak/rework the query and/or indexes in the hopes that the query planner will decide to seek (or I could force it with a join hint) and then try to benchmark it against the scan - but is it worth even trying that in this case?

This is what I'm after - an intuition of where is the boundary between the best types of join and what factors other than row count does it depend on? (e.g. how does the presence of not-reuiqred columns in the index impact the speed of the scan and/or seek?)

N.B. I'm not looking for specifics about *this* particular query or its plan (there are lots of other issues with this query and many others like it that I'm already trying to solve via other methods anyway ). I'm just looking for a general rule-of-thumb intuition.

Comment: There are literally dozens if not hundreds of entire books published about this topic. This is way too broad for a SO question.

Comment: There is no real *boundary* as a general rule. Time it yourself, or really on the optimizer, which has some rules, and has probably done a better job than anything we can come up with. The only time you need to worry about it is when it's reading a *lot* of rows and throwing away most of them. So you need to test this. I will say that a merge join can often be more efficient than a nested loop, even when it requires a sort. One option is to enable the merge join to work only on the necessary rows, by using some kind of filtered index